# Does $(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})^{11}+(\sqrt{p}-\sqrt{q})^{11}= (\sqrt{r}+\sqrt{s})^{11}+(\sqrt{r}-\sqrt{s})^{11}$ have non-trivial rational solutions?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, radicals

It has been conjectured by Euler, Ekl, etc, that
$$x_1^k+x_2^k=x_3^k+x_4^k$$
has no solution for $k>4$ if the $x_i$ are *algebraic numbers* of deg $1$.

However, if these are deg $2$, then there ***are*** solutions when $k>4$. A parametrization by Desboves is if $a^2+b^2=c^2$, then,

$$(a\sqrt2+b)^5+(-b+c\sqrt{-2})^5=(a\sqrt2-b)^5+(b+c\sqrt{-2})^5$$

***Update***: There is even for $k=11$,
$$(1+\sqrt{-7})^{11}+(1-\sqrt{-7})^{11}=(1+\sqrt{-11})^{11}+(1-\sqrt{-11})^{11}$$ which answers the title of the post, but leaves the question of how high $k$ can get.

> **Q:** But if we now consider the $x_i$ to be algebraic numbers of deg $4$ of form,
>   $$(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})^k+(\sqrt{p}-\sqrt{q})^k= (\sqrt{r}+\sqrt{s})^k+(\sqrt{r}-\sqrt{s})^k\tag1$$
>   where $p,q,r,s$ are integers, does it have non-trivial solutions for $\color{blue}{k>11}$?

It has parametric ones for $k\leq10$. (See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2096350/4781) for $k\leq6$.) Also,

---

For $k=7,9:$
$$ (\sqrt{a+c}+\sqrt{a+2b-c})^k+(\sqrt{a+c}-\sqrt{a+2b-c})^k = \\(\sqrt{a+c}+\sqrt{a-2b-c})^k+(\sqrt{a+c}-\sqrt{a-2b-c})^k$$ 
$$\begin{aligned}
&\text{If}\;k=7,\; \text{then}\; 4a^2+b^2=c^2.\\
&\text{If}\;k=9,\; \text{then}\; 6 a(a^2 + 5 b^2) + 2 b^2 c - 3 a c^2 = 0.
\end{aligned}$$

---

For $k=8,10:$
$$ (\sqrt{2a+c}+\sqrt{-2a+c})^k + (\sqrt{2a+c}-\sqrt{-2a+c})^k = \\(\sqrt{2b+c}+\sqrt{-2b+c})^k + (\sqrt{2b+c}-\sqrt{-2b+c})^k$$ 
$$\begin{aligned}
&\text{If}\;k=8,\; \text{then}\; a^2+b^2=2c^2.\\
&\text{If}\;k=10,\; \text{then}\; a^2+b^2=c^2.
\end{aligned}$$

which are just quadratics in $c$ and easily solvable. But extending these for $k=11,12$, respectively, yield *quartics* in $c$ and are harder. (And these special cases seem to always involve a *negative* integer under the square root.)

**P.S.** A [different](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2096350/4781) parameterization for $k=8$ involves, of all things, the minpoly of the *golden ratio* $\phi$ and the *plastic constant* $P$.

> **Q:** In summary, does $(1)$ have non-trivial solutions for $k>11$ as well?

(I have done a computer search, but my search radius may have been too small.)

Comment: What is the motivation behind this question? is it a research related project?

Comment: @DeepSea: Yes, you might say personal research. Why do you ask?